# Handling Ctrl-C in a Linux TCP/IP Server written in C

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I'm currently working on a Linux TCP/IP server. The server program is running in C. I'm currently testing it, but each time I exit it with Ctrl-c, the port it's using is not released, neither is the database it's been writing to unlocked. How does one define a subroutine that will exit when a Ctrl+C signal is received?

Comment: ctrl+z doesn't end a process, it merely suspends it.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Add a cleanup routine with: [int atexit(void (*function)(void));](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit)
2. Hook Ctrl+C with: [sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)

As R pointed out, [sigaction](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/sigaction/) is more portable than [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal), but perhaps less idiomatic for Linux.

Warning: atexit routines won't run if your program is killed with SIGKILL (Ctrl+/) or any other unhandled signal is received.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: regarding the socket issue, i agree with your answer.  with the database connection however...

Comment: Ah, I was too lazy to read the second half of the question. I agree about the database. And it's a signal handler that's needed, not `atexit`. Functions registered with `atexit` will not run when the process dies from an unhandled signal.

Comment: By the way, `sighandler_t` is not a standard type, and `sigaction` is a much more portable way than `signal` to install signal handlers. (POSIX allows the behavior of `signal` to vary widely, and on SysV-based systems, it tends to behave very very badly).

Comment: i agree with everything you said.  i mentioned SIGKILL in my post regarding your first point, but i could have been clearer.  i mentioned signal instead of sigaction as it seemed more idiomatic on Linux, which is the OS the OP mentioned.

Comment: i edited my post to include the points you made.  i'm new to SO, so, I hope this is viewed as good etiquette.  i intended it only to make the answer to his question more useful.

Comment: No problem, you're doing fine. :-) Ctrl+\ is `SIGQUIT` though, not `SIGKILL`. The signals `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGQUIT`, and `SIGKILL` (among others) terminate a process by default if not handled, but only `SIGKILL` (and `SIGSTOP`) cannot be blocked or caught by the application.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup `setsockopt` and `SO_REUSEADDR`. This option must have been set on the old original server process's socket or the new one will not be able to bind the port until the `TIME_WAIT` period expires.

Answer (score 1):

@Bortds Generally the port won't be released immediately, you have to wait to for some time. I  found this from a server project I worked.

Comment: @everybody It seems R..'s answer is superset of my answer.