# Ctrl + C interrupt event handling in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system, signals

I am developing an application that uses C++ and compiles using Linux GNU C Compiler.

I want to invoke a function as the user interrupts the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>  keys.

What should I do? Any answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need [Defining Signal Handlers](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html#SEC351) for SIGINT, get an idea from [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705842/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-program-work-with-less-code)

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the compiler used?

Comment: @mozcelikors There's no such thing as "libraries recognized by GCC". If there's a library written in standard C, any sane C compiler should be able to compile it.

Comment: Grijesh, could you please give me an example? I only need to define a kill event, but I don't have any idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling Ctrl-C in a Linux TCP/IP Server written in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236143/handling-ctrl-c-in-a-linux-tcp-ip-server-written-in-c)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctr + C</kbd>, the operating system sends a [signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_programming) to the process. There are many signals and one of them is SIGINT. The SIGINT ("program interrupt") is one of the Termination Signals.

There are a few more kinds of Termination Signals, but the interesting thing about SIGINT is that it can be handled (caught) by your program. The default action of SIGINT is program termination. That is, if your program doesn't specifically handle this signal, when you press <kbd>Ctr + C</kbd> your program terminates as the default action.

To change the default action of a signal you have to register the signal to be caught. To register a signal in a C program (at least under POSIX systems) there are two functions

1. [signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)
2. [sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act,
             struct sigaction *oldact);](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction).

These functions require the header [signal.h](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) to be included in your C code. I have provide a simple example of the `signal` function below with comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h> //  our new library 
volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;
void my_function(int sig){ // can be called asynchronously
  flag = 1; // set flag
}

int main(){
  // Register signals 
  signal(SIGINT, my_function); 
  //      ^          ^
  //  Which-Signal   |-- which user defined function registered
  while(1)  
    if(flag){ // my action when signal set it 1
        printf("\n Signal caught!\n");
        printf("\n default action it not termination!\n");
        flag = 0;
    }     
  return 0;
}
```

Note: you should only call [safe/authorized  functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) in signal handler. For example [avoid calling printf in signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/16891065#16891065).

You can compile this code with gcc and execute it from the shell.  There is an infinite loop in the code and it will run until you send a `SIGINT` signal by pressing <kbd>Ctr + C</kbd>.

Comment: You can leave comments for you doubts, I just try to give you a quick point of start. I believe with some more efforts you will explore the things in detail.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the process is sent a signal, not a single. :-)

Comment: @Duck hey Duck thanks man! my English is very poor, I notice your edits carefully and came to know about my mistakes. I will improve it. Thanks!

Comment: @mozcelikors remember [the library resets the signal so that the default action is performed if the same signal occurs again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728050/second-signal-call-in-sighandler-what-for/17728463#17728463)

Comment: @ Grijesh Chauhan, You're wlecome but your English isn't poor.  I just filled in some holes.

Answer (score 13):

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> normally causes the shell to send `SIGINT` to your program.  Add a handler for that signal (via [`signal(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) or [`sigaction(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction)), and you can do what you like when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is pressed.

Alternately, if you only care about doing cleanup before your program exits, setting up an exit handler via [`atexit(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) might be more appropriate.

Comment: `atexit()` is not an alternative, because the functions registered that way do not get called when the program exists due to a signal.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the signal macro.

Here is an example of how to deal with it:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void sigint(int a)
{
    printf("^C caught\n");
}
int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigint);
    for (;;) {}
}
```

Sample output:

```
Ethans-MacBook-Pro:~ phyrrus9$ ./a.out
^C^C caught
^C^C caught
^C^C caught
^C^C caught
^C^C caught
```

Comment: avoid use printf in signal handler

Comment: Simple as that. I use it to close i2c connection so the printf will be replaced with connection killing functions. Thanks really.