# C++ exception handling- taking Ctrl-z into account

Tags: c++, exception

I am a beginning programmer, and am trying to work with exception handling in C++. I found a method for validating input that seems pretty versatile, but I want to add an exception that will end the program if a user enters <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>.

Here is the function I found:

```
cout << "Please enter a decimal value:" << endl;
        while ((cin >> number).fail() || number < 0 || cin.peek() != '\n'){
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n'){ continue; cin >> number; } cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
```

I am working on a problem with vectors. I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> sends an empty string; I'm wondering if there is a way to incorporate a condition that breaks from here if number is equal to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>?

I hope that this question is clear enough.

Comment: Please see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766550/ctrl-c-interrupt-event-handling-in-linux)

Comment: @dolan's right! You can install signal handlers that in turn throw exceptions. But be careful, when using this technique with multithreaded programs. CTRL-Z actually closes `std::cin` and no there's no number you can use to pass it via `std::cin`.

Comment: Control-z in a Unix environment is associated with the SIGTSTOP signal, so keep that in mind when considering the related question @dolan found (which deals with the SIGINT signal).