# Can signal-handling be used to print intermediate results

Tags: c, signals

I frequently run programs that run for several days, testing successive integers for various criteria. I like to know where a program is up to, so I usually have it print out a message every, say, 100000000 trials, but it would be nice if I could get intermediate results by sending the program a signal. The kind of thing I have in mind is something like this:

```
Create signal handler to print out value of n and resume in loop

Register signal handler
n=1
while( 1 ) {
    If n fits some criterion, print n
    n++
}
```

with the idea that I could then use `kill -SIGTYPE processid` to get the intermediate results. Is it possible to do what I want? And if so, how? The examples I have seen that use signal handling in C all seem to exit immediately after having dealt with the signal, rather than resuming from the point where the signal was caught.

Comment: "*exit immediately after having dealt with the signal*" depends on your usage of e.g. `sigaction()` ... sure it's possible to do what you want. Just don't print from inside the signal handler, use a flag (`volatile sig_atomic_t`) instead.

Comment: I bet you have missed this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766550/ctrl-c-interrupt-event-handling-in-linux).

Comment: On which operating system? Pure standard C11 defines quite poorly what signals are and can do.

Comment: Wht kind of programs are you writing? Please **edit your question** to improve it (motivate it, give more details).

Comment: Without additional details: what OS you are coding on? what kind of application? ... your question is unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ctrl + C interrupt event handling in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766550/ctrl-c-interrupt-event-handling-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No (in principle), you should not call `printf` or `fputs` (etc...) from a signal handler, and on Linux this restriction is documented, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Take time to understand the notion of *async-signal safe* functions (the only ones you can call from inside a signal handler -even indirectly- without [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

<sup>(I guess you are on Linux, or at least on some POSIX or Unix-like system)</sup>

However, there is a usual way to overcome that: set some `volatile` [`sig_atomic_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t) flag in your signal handler, and test that flag regularly in your program main loop.

Another possibility could be to set-up (using [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)), at initialization, a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self, and have a signal handler which [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)-s one or a few bytes into that pipe (notice that [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is async-signal-safe, but `fprintf` or `malloc`  are not). Your [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) would check (using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html))  that pipe for readability and [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) it when possible. This common trick is often documented, e.g. [in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html).

Notice that [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) handling is practically OS specific (e.g. different on Linux and on Windows), and has some common behaviour in various [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) / Unix systems.

For programs running several days, you probably want them to also handle `SIGTERM`. You might then save some [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) state (e.g. in some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), in a file, perhaps using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)) and be able to restart from such a saved state. Read about [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing). You probably should think of saving (and be able to restart from) the state of your program early in its design. Perhaps you'll use [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) facilities to save e.g. every hour the state of your program (look into [setitimer(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html), [alarm(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html), `SIGALRM` etc...).

Comment: Many thanks to all who replied. The comment from @Guarav was particularly helpful as was the answer that I have marked as correct.